# Allow Standard users to add a VPN account

Tags: macos, vpn, administrator

Is there a way to allow standard users to add a VPN connection? All computers are running 10.10.3

Comment: Did you consider creating a script for that, that will enable non admin user to create a VPN?

Answer (score 1):

I found a sample of script that could be used in Automator for the non admin user to run, that would need to be customized by you (so it is a beginning). This is a example for to fire up virtualhost.sh.

To pass in your username and password to admin privileges:

```
set vhostPath to "'" & POSIX path of (path to me) & ¬
    "/Contents/Resources/virtualhost.sh" & "'"
set vhost to vhostPath & space & input
do shell script vhost user name "user" password "pass" ¬
    with administrator privileges
```

change it to match your stuff